# Best way to rotate MySQL error log by size and date

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I'm new to MySQL database, and MySQL .err log file is 10 GB in Windows environment and it's continuing to grow so, I need to configure the error log to rotate when it's 1 BG or every week whichever comes first.
So any help please to do it.

Comment: You have to figure out why the `.err` file is huge.. I'm not sure if having large `.err` file is normal or what would be considered as normal size `.err` file but if I see my `.err` file is larger than 50MB, I start worrying.. but that's just me

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help with database admin type of questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

see blog [Managing The Logs Using Linux logrotate Utility](https://scalegrid.io/blog/managing-mysql-server-logs-rotate-compress-retain-delete/)

and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/415777) is a ps;

Comment: I know but my production environment is windows server

Comment: @jalal so what your mysql version? and it's a single server or in master-slave mode. or something else.

Comment: Version: 8.0.14-commercial